# Is a question about how to develop your brain relevant to Programmers.SE?

Tags: discussion, questions

Out brain is pretty much the only tool we use. Sure a computer and an editor/IDE are necessary, but have nothing to do with being a successful or expert programmer.

So, are questions about how to develop our brain skills (which are programming meta-skills) like memory and problem-solving relevant to this site?

The FAQ does not mention them as relevant or not:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development. If you have a question about…
>
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - design patterns
> - developer testing
> - development methodologies
> - freelancing and business concerns
> - quality assurance
> - software architecture
> - software engineering
> - software licensing
>
> and it is not about…
>
> - career advice, including general workplace issues1
> - personal lifestyle, including relationships, office politics, and non-programming activities
> - what language you should learn next, including which technology is better1
> - salary or compensation1
> - résumé help
> - what project you should do next
> - programming tools (ask on Stack Overflow instead)

Comment: Our sister site [productivity.se] may be a better choice.

Comment: @Anna - It seems so...there are many similar questions.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Personal Productivity is a sister site?

Comment: @Jae Sure, why not? It's part of the SE network.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Well yeah, but isn't a sister site supposed to have a similar topic? It should be a "Cousin site" [playing devil's advocate...] ;-)

Comment: I believe [Cognitive Science][1] is the most appropriate place to ask

  [1]: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

No.

If I saw such a question I'd close it straight away.

It's not about the **profession** of software development in any way, shape or form.

Comment: If questions about brain skills are allowed on one site not specifically targeting brain skills, there's no end to the list of sites it should be allowed on. Everything requires brain skills. Physics, math, programming, cooking, gaming, writing, parenting, language... literally everything.